# Get Thumb of a Slider in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I made a custom style for a slider to which I only change the shape of the Thumb.
What I would like to do is have a function which changes the size of the Thumb whenever it is triggered (maybe via a button).
The way I created my custom style is: right-click on Slider -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy

My problem is that I don't know how can I access the thumb of the slider...
I would like something like this

```
Thumb myThumb = mySlider.GetTemplateChild("horizontalThumb");
myThumb.Height = 50;
```

I saw multiple ways to do that in WPF but not in UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Thumb from your Slider, try this:

**1**: Add the Loaded event in the XAML to your slider

**2**: Use this function to get the child from the parent

```
//Get the acutal element from the parent object using the VisualTreeHelper:
//Parameters:
//parent = The object to get the element from
//childname = The name of the childobject to find
private DependencyObject GetElementFromParent(DependencyObject parent, string childname)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is FrameworkElement childframeworkelement && childframeworkelement.Name == childname)
            return child;

        var FindRes = GetElementFromParent(child, childname);
        if (FindRes != null)
            return FindRes;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**3**: Put this code in your slider_loaded event to get the data from the Thumb:

```
private void Slider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var SliderThumb = GetElementFromParent(sender as DependencyObject, "HorizontalThumb"); //Make sure to put the right name for your slider layout options are: ("VerticalThumb", "HorizontalThumb")
    if (SliderThumb != null)
    {
        if(SliderThumb is Thumb thumb)
        {
            //Here you can change everything you like:
            thumb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            thumb.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5);
            thumb.Width = 10;
            thumb.Height = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            //SliderThumb is not an object of type Thumb
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //SliderThumb is null
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! It finally worked, I had no idea how easy it is to use VisualTreeHelper, I am new to C# and some things seems very hard to understand at first. Again, thank you a lot

Comment: You're welcome :D